# Linker in some cases complains about undefined ref. to template class static object member

Tags: c++, templates, object, static, definition

I'm new to template programming. While implementing singleton class using template, I found in some cases (as below shows) the linker complains error:

```
undefined reference to `Singleton<Test>::_lock'
```

However, if I change following statement

```
template<> Mutex Singleton<Test>::_lock;
```

to

```
template<> Mutex Singleton<Test>::_lock(1);
```

it compiles and runs without error.

Could someone helps me out and explains why in below case the compiling fails?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

class Mutex {
public:
    Mutex(){ pthread_mutex_init(&mMutex, NULL); }
    Mutex(int dummy){ pthread_mutex_init(&mMutex, NULL); }
    ~Mutex(){ pthread_mutex_destroy(&mMutex); }
    Mutex(const Mutex&) = delete;
    Mutex&      operator = (const Mutex&) = delete;

    int lock(){ return -pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex); }
    void unlock(){ pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex); }

    // Manages the mutex automatically. It'll be locked when Autolock is
    // constructed and released when Autolock goes out of scope.
    class Autolock {
    public:
        explicit Autolock(Mutex& mutex) : mLock(mutex)  { mLock.lock(); }
        ~Autolock() { mLock.unlock(); }
    private:
        Mutex& mLock;
    };

private:
    pthread_mutex_t mMutex;
};

template <typename T>
class Singleton: {
public:
    static T& Instance() {
        Mutex::Autolock _l(_lock);
        if(nullptr == _instance) {
            _instance = new T();
        }

        return *_instance;           
    }
    virtual ~Singleton(){}
    Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

private:
    static T* _instance;
    static Mutex _lock; 
};


class Test: public Singleton<Test> {
public:
    void dis() {std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;}

};

template<> Mutex Singleton<Test>::_lock;
template<> Test* Singleton<Test>::_instance(nullptr);
template class Singleton<Test>;

int main()
{
    Test::Instance().dis();    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: same as what you did with: `template<> Test* Singleton<Test>::_instance(nullptr);`?

Comment: Yes. And no problem with `template<> Test* Singleton<Test>::_instance(nullptr);`, the compiler didn't report any error regarding `_instance`. By the way I'm using gcc in ubuntu build env.

Comment: Have you split your original code onto .cpp and .h file. Unfortunately with templates all tempate-code must go into the header.